# Substance meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> **Substance:** a particular kind of matter with uniform properties
>
> The New Oxford American Dictionary (Kindle Locations 528557-528558).
> Oxford University Press. Kindle Edition.

Uni (prefix) - one

Uniform - one form

***For instance:***

a particular kind of matter with one form properties

Properties what mean here? (I confuse property, quality, attribute)

I not understand what is referring to:

> one form of properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that if you take a sample of it from anywhere within an amount of it, and test the sample for any property, quality or attribute, you will get the same result as you will from any other sample. It's all the same. That's what "uniform" means. If it's not uniform, it can't be called a single "substance".

Comment: For example, you take samples of water from a myriad of places and you notice they have the same properties, attributes, or qualities so it has uniformity and hence is a substance, that's right?

Comment: Yes, that makes it a substance. Of course, water can have impurities that may be present in different amounts in different samples, but they aren't part of its substance as water.